# How to post woocommerce checkout field html value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, alan

Hi  I have custom fields for woocommerce checkout page. 
I want to save it with html output database.
However, these are saved by cleaning html each time.
How can I save the html codes written to these fields to the database?

```
add_filter(`woocommerce_checkout_fields`, `burayi_ekle`);

function burayi_ekle($fields)
{
    $fields['billing']['billing_satis'] = [
        'type'     => 'textarea',
        'label'    => __('SATIŞ1', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'    => ['input-text'],
        'required' => true,
        'clear'    => false,
        'priority' => 120,
    ];

    $fields['billing']['billing_satis2'] = [
        'type'     => 'textarea',
        'label'    => __('SATIŞ2', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'    => ['input-text'],
        'required' => true,
        'clear'    => false,
        'priority' => 121,
    ];

    return $fields;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save WC checkout Custom fields data along with HTML into database. The record would be saved in postmeta table for the post type of Order.

Here you can try following code

```
function save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted ){
    if( isset( $posted['billing_satis'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_satis', sanitize_text_field( $posted['billing_satis'] ) );
    }
    if( isset( $posted['billing_satis2'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_satis2', $posted['billing_satis2'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Don't escape html when you add into database using update_post_meta.

Comment: I just can't make a registration for the area where I add the code I share. Woocommerce is automatically registering this field.

This is an plugin. Paste the code you've shared into the plugin page but won't work

Comment: What I understand is you're using plugins for registering above two fields and it removes the HTML before saving it into database. 
You can paste above code into your active theme's funtions.php file.

If you're sure with the fields name you can unset and then register by your self with different name using your code and then make changes in my code with new name of fields.

This way you can overwrite plugins field saving by it's way. Using this you have some extra work to show and save those fields into wp-admin.

Comment: (https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-edit-delete-fields-and-email-in-woocommerce-custom-checkout-fields/) you can read more in details here.

Comment: It's the same which I suggested. If you could accept my answer please do mark it as accepted and write what was the issue you were facing actually and how did you fixed that. It will help other fellows in future.

Answer (score 1):

Okey . i fix it .

This is my true code

```
function save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id ){

        $billing_satis = $_POST['billing_satis'];
        if(   ! empty($billing_satis) ){
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_satis', $billing_satis  );
        }

        $billing_satis2 = $_POST['billing_satis2'];
        if(   ! empty($billing_satis2) ){
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_ billing_satis2', $billing_satis2 );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
```